# JMeter using HTTP Request Defaults config element

Tags: performance, jmeter

I see from the JMeter documentation it is possible to add parameters for HTTP Requestsin your test group: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults

But say you have twenty threads in your test group, how do you vary the parameter value for each thread?

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the pre processor User Parameters to the Test Group.
2. Add a few users
3. Select Add variable
4. For name: myparamete
5. Add the values in for the various users
6. Go to the HTTP Request Defaults config element
7. Set the parameter myparameter = to %{myparameter}

Enjoy